# How to obtain the density of a sum of independent discrete random variables?

Tags: r, self-study, discrete-data, convolution

Let's $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$, $n=1,2,...$ are independent discrete random variables.

It is necessary to find the distribution law of the their sum:

$p(k) =P(X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n = k), k=0, 1, 2, ... $

I solved the problem case $n=3$ when random variables take the same values $x=\{0,1,2\}$ ​​and probabilities $p =\{0.85, 0.1, 0.05\}$ using the convolution twice.

```
x <- x0 <- c(0:2)             # value's of random variable 
p <- p0 <- c(0.85, 0.1, 0.05) # probabilities

n = 2 

for(i in 1:n){
p1 <- outer(p0, p)
d1 <- outer(x0, x, `+`)
z1 <- tapply(p1, d1, sum)
p <- z1
x <- as.integer(names(z1))
}
z1
#        0        1        2        3        4        5        6 
# 0.614125 0.216750 0.133875 0.026500 0.007875 0.000750 0.000125
```

**Question.** I am looking for a function/packages for obtaining the density of a sum of independent discret random variables.

Comment: What do you know about the distributions of the variables besides that they are discrete?

Comment: They are independed. Just a small table with values and probabilities.

Comment: The probability function (not density!) of the sum is the *convolution* of their probability functions.  When the values lie on a lattice (*e.g.*, they are all integers) this is efficiently computed using the Fast Fourier Transform.  That is implemented in `R` as `fft`.  Look also at the `convolve` function. See, *inter alia,* https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41251, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41247, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191193, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5347.

Answer (score 1):

There are [many kinds of discrete distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Discrete_distributions). The result would be simple for some of them, for example with $X_i \sim \mathcal{Pois}(\lambda_i)$ we know that $\sum_i X_i \sim \mathcal{Pois}(\sum_i \lambda_i)$. But for others, it might be more complicated.

You seem to be referring to the [categorical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution). With two categories, it would be a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution), where the sum of i.i.d. Bernoulli's would follow a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), but if they are independent but not identically distributed it quickly gets pretty nasty and results in [Poisson-binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). Because of that, in many cases, we would [rather approximate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177199/success-of-bernoulli-trials-with-different-probabilities/177207#177207) the distribution than calculate the probabilities directly. Sum of i.i.d. categorical distributions result in [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), and if they are not identically distributed it is a Poisson-multinomial distribution (see e.g. [Lin, Wang, and Hong, 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.04237)) that again, is pretty complicated. Hopefully, there seems to be an [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PoissonMultinomial/index.html) implementing it that exposes both direct and approximate methods for calculating it (I never used it, so don't take it as a recommendation).